# scraping hidden data within an a tag

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, href

am trying to scrape  info from this website `https://www.heiminfo.ch/institutionen`
the HTML looks like this where the info am looking for is stored.

```
<article class="institution card pushed" data-name="HOF SPEICHER AG - (di Gallo)" data-institution-type="HIALTER HIEB CVAPPENZELLALTER" data-subscription="SILBER" data-zoom="15" data-track-content="" data-content-target="Huta5R8" data-lng="9.441113" data-group="Kurt di Gallo Holding AG" data-content-piece="Huta5R8" data-content-name="Institution View List" data-lat="47.41353" style="height: 249.95px;" data-ol-has-click-handler="">
            <a href="/institution/hof-speicher-ag/Huta5R8" data-remote-url="" data-id="Huta5R8" data-ol-has-click-handler="">
                <div class="img-container">
                    
                        <img class=" lazyloaded" width="450" src="/filesystem/clientadditionportrait/2018/02/698FA7D4-F5A4-89B4-8CE87700B6C2D216/images/fit/Hof-Speicher1-w-450-hc19BB84B3.jpg" data-src="/filesystem/clientadditionportrait/2018/02/698FA7D4-F5A4-89B4-8CE87700B6C2D216/images/fit/Hof-Speicher1-w-450-hc19BB84B3.jpg" alt="HOF SPEICHER AG">
                    
                </div>
                
                
                <div class="text-container" style="height: 114.99px;">
                    <div class="name-and-addition">
                        <h2 style=""><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">HOF SPEICHER AG </font></font></h2>
                        
                            <p class="addition" style=""><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">(di Gallo)</font></font></p>
                        
                    </div>
                    
                    <p class="location">
                        <span class="canton"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">AR </font></font></span>
                        <span class="plz"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">9042 </font></font></span>
                        <span class="city"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">memory</font></font></span>
                    </p>
                    
    
                </div>
            </a>
        </article>
```

I've been able to obtain first 500 institution names,city, plz, location.
using this code:courtesy of **Arundeep Chohan**

```
    import requests
    import time
    import pandas  as  pd
    import csv
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from time import sleep
    from random import randint
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    from selenium import webdriver as wb
    driver=wb.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.get(' https://www.heiminfo.ch/institutionen')
    button=driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/main/div/section/form/div[1]/div[3]/div/button[3]').click();



  wait=WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
total=500
h=[]
while True:
    try:
        soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
        item=soup.find(class_='institutions')
        #item=driver.find_element_by_class_name('institutions')
        lsh=item.find_all(class_="name-and-addition")
        #lsh=item.find_element_by_class_name('name-and-addition')
        if(len(lsh)>=total):
            for e in lsh[:total]:
                h(e.text.strip)
                data=pd.DataFrame(zip(h), columns=['Adult Homes'])
            print(data)
            break
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".next.btn"))).click()
        time.sleep(5)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        break
```

the remaining info is the phone number which hidden within the tag "`<a> href=`", which I have to click to open to obtain the telephone number. the totals number of these "`<a> href=`"  is 1589.
how can I write a  scraper to iterate thru' all these links and obtain the hidden telephone number? the links look like this :

```
 [<a href="/institution/hof-speicher-ag/Huta5R8" data-remote-url="" data-id="Huta5R8" data-ol-has-click-handler="">][1]
```

Comment: You need to click on the individual links to be able to see the telephone number.

Comment: no way to iterate thru' 1589 links? I do that 1589  times manually?